# Running multiple commands with bash without spawning subshells

Tags: bash

```
cd folder &>/dev/null ||( mkdir folder && cd folder ) && git clone https://github.com/user/my-project.git
```

when running the above command I have the problem (I think), that the `()` spawns a subshell and runs the commands, then when running the git clone I'm not in the expected directory. Is there a way to run this line? My current solution is

```
cd folder &>/dev/null || mkdir folder && cd folder && git clone https://github.com/user/my-project.git
```

The thing is, I run `cd folder` twice even if the directory exists

Comment: BTW, `a && b || c` is *not* the same as `if a; then b; else c; fi`. Using boolean logic, you can have `a` succeed, `b` fail, and then `c` succeed (thus causing the whole command to return a successful exit status, despite the unexpected failure); using the `if`, `c` will **only** happen if `a` fails, and not be invoked if `b` fails. Which is to say -- bash doesn't have a ternary operator; pretending it does is a fast route to hard-to-catch bugs.

Comment: @Charles: But surely in this case, OP really meant `{ a || b; } && c`; that is, the desire is to run `git ...` assuming that one of `a` or `b` succeeded. Which is exactly what `a || b && c` does in bash, however confusing that may be to people used to C operator precedence,

Comment: Rodrigo: `cd folder` is so cheap that it is not worth doing any work to avoid it. The real problem with this command line is the race condition noted by @CharlesDuffy in a comment to my answer (which I then edited into my answer).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### 1. How to avoid spawning a subshell

There are two grouping operators in shell:

- `( commands… )` Runs commands in a subshell
- `{ commands… }` Runs commands in the current execution environment.

But please be aware that <kbd>(</kbd> and <kbd>)</kbd> are shell *meta-characters* while <kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>}</kbd> are not. The braces are reserved words, but only if they are complete words and appear as the first word in a command. So the braces need to be surrounded by spaces and the closing brace must come after a semi-colon. For a longer explanation, see [Bash command groups: Why do curly braces require a semicolon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246552/bash-command-groups-why-do-curly-braces-require-a-semicolon/21246590).

Specifically, you would have to write

```
cd folder &>/dev/null || { mkdir folder && cd folder; } && git clone https://github.com/user/my-project.git
```

Note the explicit semicolon to terminate the pipeline. You could have used it in the subshell compound command, too, but here you *must* use it.

However, you shouldn't really use this command, because it could fail if another process happened to create the directory `folder` after the first `cd` fails and before the `mkdir` runs. There is a better way:

#### 2. How to make this command simpler and more robust

Because this is a very common task indeed, `mkdir` comes with the useful `-p` option (this option is required by Posix).

```
mkdir -p some/path
```

does two things differently:

1. The intermediate directories are *also* created, if necessary
2. No error is produced if the final directory already exists.

So the common idiom for tasks like this is:

```
mkdir -p folder && cd folder && git clone https://github.com/user/my-project.git
```

which would work even if `folder` were a complete path and more than one directory along the path needed to be added.

Answer (score 1):

The () does spawn a sub-shell. Here's an example of a one-line command that might be helpful:

```
if [ ! -d folder ]; then mkdir folder; fi; cd folder && git clone ...
```

Comment: This differs from the OP's code insofar as it runs the `git clone` even if the `cd` failed (and thus can clone into the wrong directory if a `folder` already exists but the current user doesn't have `+x` permissions to change into it).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good catch, should be fixed now.